# JWT is not configurated properly, please contact the admin

Tags: wordpress, api, jwt

Estoy intentando hacer mas segura mi conexión con mi API Rest y para ello he instalado en mi wordpress el plugin `JWT Authentication for WP-API`, he seguido todos los pasos:

**.htaccess**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**wp-config:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al ejecutar en `POSTMAN` :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo lo que veo en internet esta configurado y no se que me falta.

Comment: agregastes en el header el jwt?

Comment: perdona por mi ignorancia,pero que header?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth/issues/59

Mueve la definición de **JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY** a la parte superior de tu archivo **wp-config.php** 
(la definición de **JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY** debe realizarse antes de `require_once (ABSPATH. 'wp-settings.php');`)